# Использование кавычек

Tags: кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно "закавычить" в следующем предложении?
*В переводе с таджикского ремонт означает вечность.*

Вечность? Или ремонт тоже?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предложении между "ремонт" и "вечность" есть слово "означает", которое позволяет не ставить никаких кавычек:

*В переводе с таджикского ремонт означает вечность.*

Вариант с кавычками тоже допустим, особенно если учитывать заключённую в высказывании иронию:

*В переводе с таджикского "ремонт" означает "вечность"?*